# Will this MySQL index increase performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, select, indexing

I have the following MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tstamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to optimise for the following `SELECT` query only:

```
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `my_data` ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

Will adding the following index increase performance, regardless of the size of the table?

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_name_id` ON `my_data` (`name`,`id`);
```

An `EXPLAIN` query suggests it would, but I have no quick way of testing with a large data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would. Even though you are still doing a full table scan, having the index will make the sort operation (due to the order by) unnecessary.

But it will also add overhead to inserts and delete statements!

Comment: my bad, I missed the order part that would obviously benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks @Miky. Only interested in optimising for that specific SELECT query.

Answer (score 1):

**Index** are usefull when you use the column in the **where clause**, or when the column is a part of the condition for a **link between two tables**. [See MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)